# Arduino nano not responding

Tags: arduino

Few months ago, I bought cheap arduino nano from china. Instaled all the required drivers, and tried out my frirst program.
Now I tried to upload something new, and I get this error message:
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM4": System can't find given file.
I also noticed, that Tools->Ports can not be clicked. The device does not even show up in device manager.
Any Ideas?

In my first program I did also set pin 0 and 1 (RX/TX) as outputs and used them to flash LEDs. I am aware, that this probably prevents new code from beeing uploded, but it should not prevent from the device from shoving up at all. The computer talking to the USB driver, not the microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device Manager and find the Arduino COM Port

[image]

Go to the Advanced properties of the port

[image]

Set the port # to COM1

[image]

Then un-plug your USB and plug it back in.